# Developer hyperlink to edit from WP website

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, footer, edit, elementor

My wordpress site has a footer hyperlink of the developer, I want to change it, but I am unable to, I have tried through appearance, then with the elementor footer but that remains unchanged. Could anybody please guide? The website is www.11c dot in

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Appearance > Theme-Editor and look in "footer.php" for `<footer` and delete it if it's there.
OR as you have two `footer`-tags, you can hide the mentioned one with `footer:not(#colophon) { display: none; }` in Custom CSS.

Comment: Thanks, this is how it shows,   https://justpaste.it/6l8k5  please advise or edit. Will be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, this is way to complex.
You can look for **parts of this** in the database and search thru all template files:
 
`<footer style="background-color:#000; text-align:center; font-size: 16px; color:#dbac54;">© 2020 11Creations Powered By <a style="color:#8c7243"; :hover{color:#dbac54;};" href="https://www.srkptechnologies.com/">SRKP Technologies</a></footer>`
 
Or the quick and dirty way: hide it with the CSS code above.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit/remove it if you go to your Customizer (Appearance > Customize > Footer Bottom